# Huge random blank space before and after equation

Tags: equations

i have to reach in my thesis today and of course something like this had to happen on the last day...

After compiling the document, huge blank spots appeared before and after this equation. And i don't have any clue why as I did not change anything around this text section.

Here's the code section:

```
Im Gegensatz zu Kapitel \ref{4.2.3} sind nun T\textsubscript{SP1} und DTN\textsubscript{WÜ1} variabel, wodurch sich der COP für jedes betrachtete Fluid leicht ändert. Der Druck p\textsubscript{BE6} wird so angepasst, dass Gleichung \ref{eq WÜ3 1 K} gilt. 
\begin{equation}
    T\textsubscript{FW2} = T\textsubscript{BE6} + PP
    \label{eq WÜ3 1 K}
\end{equation}
Daraus ergeben sich p\textsubscript{BE6, PP=1K} = 38,68 bar und p\textsubscript{BE6, PP=0.1K} = 39,48 bar. Der Druck p\textsubscript{BE5} wird so festgelegt, dass x\textsubscript{BE5} = 0 \% immer eingehalten wird, woraus sich folgende Werte ergeben: p\textsubscript{BE5, PP=1K} = 55,70 bar und p\textsubscript{BE5, PP=0.1K} = 55,66 bar. \\ \\
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? It's urgent...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is please the small compilable code where you have the problem? Thus we can see the eventual problem.

Comment: Odds are the next page starts with a large unbreakable box, such as a figure [H].

Comment: You end your example with `\\ \\ ` to force the blank line.  That makes me wonder if you're using `\\ ` to end your paragraphs.  If you do that, it merges the paragraphs into one gigantic paragraph that becomes a large unbreakable box.  Instead, use blank lines in your source code to start new paragraphs.  If you need a blank line between paragraphs, use `\bigskip` at the end of the previous paragraph.

Comment: latex does not produce random output, it  produces output determined by the input you give it. You have provided no example code but I would guess you have a large unbreakable box at the top of the following page, and you have `\flushbottom` so force latex to stretch this page.

Comment: You write, "It's urgent". Then please do yourself a big favor and provide some much-needed pieces of information about your document setup, starting with (a) the document class you employ and (b) the packages you load, including the options with which the packages are loaded. Do also provide some information about what comes immediately before and immediately after the  problem behavior you wish to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Im Gegensatz zu Kapitel \ref{4.2.3} sind nun T\textsubscript{SP1} und DTN\textsubscript{WÜ1} variabel, wodurch sich der COP für jedes betrachtete Fluid leicht ändert. Der Druck p\textsubscript{BE6} wird so angepasst, dass Gleichung \ref{eq WÜ3 1 K} gilt. 
\begin{equation}
    T\textsubscript{FW2} = T\textsubscript{BE6} + PP
    \label{eq WÜ3 1 K}
\end{equation}
Daraus ergeben sich p\textsubscript{BE6, PP=1K} = 38,68 bar und p\textsubscript{BE6, PP=0.1K} = 39,48 bar. Der Druck p\textsubscript{BE5} wird so festgelegt, dass x\textsubscript{BE5} = 0 \% immer eingehalten wird, woraus sich folgende Werte ergeben: p\textsubscript{BE5, PP=1K} = 55,70 bar und p\textsubscript{BE5, PP=0.1K} = 55,66 bar. \\ \\
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image: Output]

I'm afraid you may have to isolate parts from your preamble and figure out what is causing the problem.

Lastly, a band-aid solution would be to use `\vspace{-2cm}` or something before and after the equation to remove the spaces.

Comment: A quick hint from a long-time member of this community: When an OP fails to provide lots of information relevant for diagnosing the situation at hand, it hardly ever pays to go ahead and provide an answer that will be  based, by necessity, on various types of educated guesses. No matter how well-intentioned you may be, the likelihood that your answer will actually help resolve the OP's issue is between small and negligibly small. It's almost always better to wait for the OP to steps up and provide the crucial bits of information.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks :)